# Firebase token in URL

Tags: android, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging, trusted-web-activity

I've followed [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/blob/main/demos/twa-firebase-analytics/src/main/java/com/google/androidbrowserhelper/demos/twa_firebase_analytics/FirebaseAnalyticsLauncherActivity.java) method to send my fcm token in the URL.

Following is my custom launcher activity

```
public class LauncherActivity
    extends com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity {

private String fcmToken;

@Override
protected Uri getLaunchingUrl() {
    Uri uri = super.getLaunchingUrl();
        return uri
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("fcmToken", fcmToken)
                .build();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    fcmToken = task.getResult();
                    launchTwa();
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldLaunchImmediately() {
        return false;
}
```

Problem is when i run the app for the first time it get stuck in the splash screen.Then after killing the app , second time onward it works.

This issues is discussed in [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/issues/281) as well , but with no luck.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since i didn't find and resolution to this , following is the way i found to overcome this issue.Now i don't have the stuck in initial step and already token is passed to my server.

LauncherActivity.java

```
public class LauncherActivity
        extends com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity {

    private String fcmToken;

    @Override
    protected Uri getLaunchingUrl() {
            uri = super.getLaunchingUrl();
       
            return uri
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("fcmToken", fcmToken)
                    .build();
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean shouldLaunchImmediately() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        fcmToken = preferences.getString("fcmTokenNew", "");
        Boolean res = false;
        if(fcmToken != null && !fcmToken.trim().isEmpty()) {
            res = true;
        }
        return res;
    }


}
```

CustomFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
public class CustomFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    
        @Override
        public void onNewToken(String token) {
            sendToSariroti(token);
        }
    
        protected void sendToServer(String fcmToken) {
    
            try {
    
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("fcmTokenNew",fcmToken);
                editor.apply();
    
                Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                        getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

What is happening is when you first launch the app,

- It checks whether the parameter(fcmToken) is not null/available inside shouldLaunchImmediately If it's available , no problem , continue with launching the app
- If token not available stop launching the app
- Inside onNewToken , it watches until token is received from Firebase.
- After it received it will call sendToServer.
- Inside sendToServer, it store the fcmToken in shared preference and re-launch the app again.

Hope this will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been handled in version [2.2.2](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/pull/297) of android-browser-helper. For versions before that you can call `onEnterAnimationComplete()` after calling `launchTwa()`. You can find more info about this workaround [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/issues/281)